# Working out the rate of growth at a weekly rate

Tags: statistics

This is likely to be a very basic question but I'm struggling to get my head around it, so hopefully someone can help.

I'm looking at product growth rate based on the number of visits over a series of weeks. 
i.e.

Week 1 - 100 visits
Week 2 - 120 visits
Week 3 - 200 visits
Week 4 - 500 visits

etc...

My question is how do I work out the rate of growth of this product? Is it simply finding the average rate of growth or the rate of growth between Week 1 and Week 4? OR can you both depending on how you define "rate of growth"?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to do depends on how you interpret "rate of growth" and what you want it for.

In Calculus, one distinguishes between *average rate of growth over an interval* and *instantaneous rate of growth*, the latter being the limit of the former as the time interval under consideration shrinks to zero length. This shrinking to zero is not feasible for the kind of data you have. Thus, the meaningful quantity is the average rate of growth over an interval  of time. Its value will  depend on your choice of the time interval.

Over four weeks, the visits grew from 500/week to 100/week. This means average growth rate over this interval was (500-100)/4 = 100/week  per week. (Awkward but inevitable construction at the end; this is similar to how  the rate of change of velocity is measured in meters per second per second.)